# After loop always nil in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cycle

When I try cycle the rails array I have still nil, even when array already defined.

The code:

```
def gen_address
  current_user.accounts.each do |account|
    abort(@account.inspect)
    next if not account.currency_obj.coin?

    if account.payment_addresses.blank?
      account.payment_addresses.create(currency: account.currency)
    else
      address = account.payment_addresses.last
      address.gen_address if address.address.blank?
    end
  end
  render nothing: true
end
```

current_user.accounts have array with three items. abort is there for testing only.

current_user.accounts have:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Account id: 14, member_id: 3, currency: nil, balance: 0.0, locked: 0.0, created_at: "2017-05-23 08:50:11", updated_at: "2017-05-23 08:50:16", in: nil, out: nil, default_withdraw_fund_source_id: nil>, #<Account id: 5, member_id: 3, currency: "btc", balance: 0.0, locked: 0.0, created_at: "2017-05-03 08:37:19", updated_at: "2017-05-03 08:37:19", in: nil, out: nil, default_withdraw_fund_source_id: nil>, #<Account id: 6, member_id: 3, currency: "ltc", balance: 0.0, locked: 0.0, created_at: "2017-05-03 08:37:19", updated_at: "2017-05-03 08:37:19", in: nil, out: nil, default_withdraw_fund_source_id: nil>, #<Account id: 13, member_id: 3, currency: "eth", balance: 0.0, locked: 0.0, created_at: "2017-05-23 08:42:29", updated_at: "2017-05-23 08:42:35", in: nil, out: nil, default_withdraw_fund_source_id: nil>]>
```

account is always nil

currency_obj is:

```
module HashCurrencible
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def currency_obj
      Currency.find_by_code(attributes[:currency])
    end
  end
end
```

I get this error for row next if not account.currency_obj.coin?, when remove abort:

```
undefined method `coin?' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Could you post your User and Account models and the error you are getting? Where are you getting nil?

Comment: Sure, I updated the question

Comment: is `current_user.accounts[0]` or `@account` nil?

Comment: Be aware that `@account` is not the same thing as `account` within your block. If you intend to inspect `account` in each iteration, you need to use the local variable, not an instance variable that happens to have the same name.

Comment: What does the `currency_obj` method do?

Comment: I update my question. Currency_obj is inside question now. My question is how to get all the information for account inside the loop. Still the nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currenc_obj` is `nil`, so it can't respond to `coin?` method; check this line:

```
#<Account id: 14, member_id: 3, currency: nil, balance: 0.0, locked: 0.0, created_at: "2017-05-23 08:50:11", updated_at: "2017-05-23 08:50:16", in: nil, out: nil, default_withdraw_fund_source_id: nil
```

In your first `Account` object, the attribute `:currency` is `nil` so the method `currency_obj` will return `nil` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The variable account has scope only to the loop. So it will be nil outside the loop.

Comment: It depends on what you need actually I could see function so you can declared a variable outside with nil value and assign the account to it, if you want all the account create an empty array and push the acoount inside the loop

Comment: I thoght that account.currency_obj.coin will inject coin to Currency.find_by_code(attributes[:currency]), but if not, how to do that?